# SBT compile always gives " GC overhead limit exceeded error" irrespective of the heap size

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, sbt

sbt 0.13.8 compile  takes a very long time (> 25 mins) and finally errors out with  GC overhead limit

```
[info] Compiling 323 Scala sources and 1 Java source to .../target/scala-2.12/classes ...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to .../java_pid10265.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [7078096837 bytes in 71.966 secs]
[error] ## Exception when compiling 324 sources to .../target/scala-2.12/classes
[error] GC overhead limit exceeded
[error] scala.reflect.internal.util.HashSet.growTable(HashSet.scala:97)
[error] scala.reflect.internal.util.HashSet.addEntry(HashSet.scala:63)
...
[addJava] arg = '-Xmx4G'
[addJava] arg = '-Xms1024m'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:HeapDumpPath=....
```

**Information from hprof file:**

```
Basic info:
    Date taken: Wed Mar 20 15:04:26 PDT 2019
    File: .../java_pid10265.hprof
    File size: 6,750.2 MB

    Total bytes: 6,033,077,813
    Total classes: 22,538
    Total instances: 116,328,564
    Classloaders: 163
    GC roots: 3,101
    Number of objects pending for finalization: 0

    Heap dumped on OutOfMemoryError exception
    Thread causing OutOfMemoryError exception: pool-6-thread-8

  Environment:
    OS: Linux (3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64)
    Architecture: amd64 64bit
    Java Home: /mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre
    Java Version: 1.8.0_144
    JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01, mixed mode)
    Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation

  System properties:
    awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9933
    com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    file.encoding=UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
    file.separator=/
    java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path=/mnt/software/s/sbt/0.13.8/bin/sbt-launch.jar
    java.class.version=52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs=/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs=/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home=/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre
    java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
    java.library.path=/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/amd64/server:/mnt/software/h/htslib/1.9/lib:/mnt/software/z/zlib/1.2.11/lib:/mnt/software/g/gcc/6.4.0/libc-2.5/compat/lib:/mnt/software/g/gcc/6.4.0/libc-2.5/lib64:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_71/jre/lib/amd64/server:/mnt/software/o/openblas/0.2.14/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.rmi.server.randomIDs=true
    java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version=1.8.0_144-b01
    java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version=1.8
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version=1.8.0_144
    java.vm.info=mixed mode
    java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version=1.8
    java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version=25.144-b01
    jline.esc.timeout=0
    jline.shutdownhook=false
    jna.loaded=true
    jna.nosys=true
    jna.platform.library.path=/usr/lib64:/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libvmGuestLibJava.so:/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libvmGuestLibJava.so:/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libvmGuestLib.so:/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libvmGuestLib.so:/usr/lib64/mysql:/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libDeployPkg.so:/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libDeployPkg.so
    jnidispatch.path=/tmp/jna--845103277/jna1647140300662886831.tmp
    line.separator=\n
    os.arch=amd64
    os.name=Linux
    os.version=3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
    path.separator=:
    sbt.log.noformat=true
    sun.arch.data.model=64
    sun.boot.class.path=/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/resources.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/rt.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/jce.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path=/mnt/software/j/jdk/1.8.0_144/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian=little
    sun.cpu.isalist=
    sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command=/mnt/software/s/sbt/0.13.8/bin/sbt-launch.jar smrt-server-link/compile
    sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level=unknown
```

Tried increasing the heap max upto 32G, same problem happens after a long time with bigger hprof file.
Visual VM shows 100% GC activity and all of the allocated heap is being used.

Comment: “Visual VM shows 100% GC activity” is in line with the message of the `OutOfMemoryError`, as “GC overhead limit exceeded” implies that the JVM has given up after detecting that it spent more than 98% of its time in GC activity. What’s strange about it, is that giving the JVM significantly more memory didn’t solve the issue. This implies that sbt has a habit of consuming resource when you give them to it, without a possibility of reclaiming (some kind of memory leak). A thread name like “`pool-6-thread-8`” raises the question how many pool and threads are actually there in total…

Comment: I too thought it was probably memory leak. It turns out be to a problem with automatic derivation. There was something undefined in the code that was getting compiled that seemed to cause this issue.